# Index out of range in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I m trying to retrieve all the data in the isolated storage file.
But i get a  index out of range error.
home^how^yo^

```
StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("AlarmFolder\\alarm.txt", FileMode.Open, myStore));

string[] alarmDetailsSeparated;

String fileText = readFile.ReadLine();


//alarmDetailsSeparated is the array that hold the retrieved alarm details from alarm.txt and is split by '^'
alarmDetailsSeparated = fileText.Split(new char[] { '^' });

foreach (string home in alarmDetailsSeparated)
{
    for (i = 0; i < alarmDetailsSeparated.Length;)
    {
        if (test > 0)
        {
            i = test;
        }

        dateSeparate = alarmDetailsSeparated[i];
        timeSeparate = alarmDetailsSeparated[i + 1];
        labelSeparate = alarmDetailsSeparated[i + 2];

        date = dateSeparate;
        time = timeSeparate;
        label = labelSeparate;

        test = test + 3 ;
        break;
    }

    MessageBox.Show("i is " + alarmDetailsSeparated[i]);
    MessageBox.Show("i + 1 is " + alarmDetailsSeparated[i + 1]);
    MessageBox.Show("i + 2 is " + alarmDetailsSeparated[i + 2]);
}
```

Comment: If you know how many elements are supposed to be in the `alarmDetailsSeparated`, why not index them directly instead of looping through them?
You should, of course, verify that the expected number of elements actually is present though.

Comment: Your for-loop looks really odd and it's unclear where `test` is declared and what it contains.

Comment: can u give me a example? i not very sure about how to do that

Comment: @ben tar You're already doing it: `dateSeparate = alarmDetailsSeparated[i];`
Just use `dateSeparate = alarmDetailsSeparated[0]` and so forth instead.

Comment: i am not very sure.. actually what i want was to get every first 2 data and so on..

Comment: i tried this way but the loop never come to an end

Comment: @ben tar If the file contains a variable number of items separated by ^, then you have to loop over them. If so disregard my previous comments.

Comment: Also, you don't need both a nested `foreach` and `for` loop iterating over the same array.
You can essentially remove the `foreach` loop since you never use the loop variable `home`.

Comment: i removed the foreach loop.. but it only loop for one time when there is 2 data inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, IIUC your storage file looks something like this:

```
home^date^time^label
home^date^time^label
...
```

and you want to do processing on each alarm data entry in the file.

The first thing you need to do is split it on each line:

```
string[] lines = file.ReadAllLines("alarms.dat");
foreach (line in lines) {
    // handle the alarm data entry (see below)
}
```

Now you can do the split as you are doing in your code:

```
string[] data = line.Split(new char[] { '^' });
```

This should give you 4 entries if the line has the data you want, so check for this:

```
if (data.Length == 4) { // looks like an alarm data entry
    // do processing on the alarm data entry (see below)
}
```

the data can now be extracted:

```
string home = data[0];
string date = data[1];
string time = date[2];
string label = date[3];
```

And then acted on:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("home {0} at {1} on date {2} with label {3}",
                home, time, date, label));
```

Comment: hi my data is saved in the isolated storage file in a single line such that is look like this.. home^date^time^label^home^date^time^label^home^date^time^label^.......

Answer (score 1):

In the loop, you are going from `0` to the length of `alarmDetailsSeparated`. This is fine, but you are then indexing `alarmDetailsSeparated` using `i+1` and `i+2`.

This means that when the loop is at `alarmDetailsSeparated.Length-2` the program will index `alarmDetailsSeparated.Length-2+2 = alarmDetailsSeparated.Length` and throw an out of bounds error.

Comment: try: `for (i = 0; i < alarmDetailsSeparated.Length; i += 3)` as you are processing 3 items at a time.

Comment: I tried to do the i+=3.. 
But i have a warning form visual studio stating that Unreachable code detected for i+=3

Answer (score 1):

```
dateSeparate = alarmDetailsSeparated[i];
timeSeparate = alarmDetailsSeparated[i + 1];
labelSeparate = alarmDetailsSeparated[i + 2];
```

The last 2 lines are the problematic ones: if you are looping from 0 to alarmDetailsSeperated length, there is no guarantee that the current index + 1, or +2 exists, thus making this code not safe (as you see, you are getting an exception).

An easy solution would be to modify your loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < alarmDetailsSeparated.Length - 2;)
```

Comment: The only missing piece is what value does 'test' take when the loop is initialized ? and why is it needed?

Comment: test take the value of 0 and 3 when it is loop for the first time.. i put the test in to make it continue looping instead of looping for only one time

Comment: After it takes the value of 3, the inner loop is exit, but the external foreach loop is now assigning home to the value of the 2nd string in the array. You are now entering the inner loop with test = 3, assigning this value to i in an unsafe manner, and failing. What is the use for the external loop? get rid of it.